# Remote Desktop DPI nightmare in Windows 8.1/2012 R2 - how can I fix it?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, remote-desktop, high-dpi, microsoft-surface-pro

Several of my users have 1 Surface Pro 3 (Windows 8.1 with all updates) and 2 ViewSonic monitorsand they connect to our servers using Remote Desktop 2012 R2.

All screens are fine on client, but when using Remote Desktop, I get this problem...

Take a look at this screencapture of my ViewSonic screen (from RD session):

[image]

(Full size: http://tinyurl.com/mmyl2rr)

Outlook in the back is normal size - but very blurry.

Adobe PDF reader in front is HUGE letters and is sharp.

Our own develloped CRM system (not shown in the image) is normal size and not blurry.

Before my user got the Surface Pro 3, he had a Dell Tower Pc with the same screens attached - all worked perfectly fine.

Is this due to DPI and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

Screen sizes ... 
Surface Pro 3: 2160x1440
ViewSonic: 1680x1050

Comment: what is the screen resolution set to?

Comment: Forgot to write that problem exists in RD session.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem of explorer.exe and other programs not scaling up / down correctly to match the DPI settings.

RDP 8.1 (Win 8.1 and 2012R2) supports remoting of the DPI settings from the client to the server. Unfortunately, the server is not able to act on these DPI settings "live" for all programs, so some programs end up using the DPI from before the remote session was started, while others use the correct DPI setting that the clients request.

The "fix" (while it is truly a rather bad workaround) is to logoff the existing session and let RDP start a new session when you make a new connection. This will guarantee that the new session will have the proper DPI settings. Sorry :(

/cd